Increasing size of a letter - Graphics 8086 MASM
So, I am working on graphics in MASM 8086, I wrote something that can display a letter 'D' on the screen however it is small, I tried to raise size of my array but then I tried setting the coordinates however it kept distorting my 'D' and it still wasn't being drawn properly (largely) so i was wondering if anyone can help me? I am new to graphics, and would appreciate any insight.
.model small
.stack 0100h
.data

; Define colors
Hert    db 04,04,04,04,00,00,00,00,00 ; Define top half of 'D'
        db 04,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00
        db 04,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00
        db 04,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00
        db 04,00,00,00,04,00,00,00,00
        db 04,04,04,04,00,00,00,00,00 ; Define bottom half of 'D'
        
; Coordinate definitions for drawing
xi dw 0
xf dw 0
yi dw 0
yf dw 0

.code
main proc
    ; Initialize DS to point to the data segment
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    ; Set video mode to 320x200, 256 colors
    mov al, 13h
    mov ah, 00h
    int 10H

    ; Set coordinates for drawing the 'D'
    mov si, offset Hert
    mov yi, 30
    mov yf, 36
    mov xi, 30
    mov xf, 39 
    call draw
    
    ; Exit program
    mov ah, 04ch
    int 21h
main endp

; Draw procedure to plot the 'D' on screen
draw proc
    mov ah, 0ch          ; Function to plot pixel
    mov dx, yi           ; Y coordinate start
y:
    mov cx, xi           ; X coordinate start
x:
    mov al, [si]         ; Get pixel color value
    int 10h              ; Draw pixel
    inc si               ; Move to next pixel in data
    inc cx               ; Increment X coordinate
    cmp cx, xf           ; Check if end of X reached
    jb x
    inc dx               ; Move to next line in Y
    cmp dx, yf           ; Check if end of Y reached
    jb y
    ret
draw endp

end

I tried tweaking the coordinates but that wasn't very useful, I also tried to increase the size of my array but to no avail.

One solution would keep the array as it is, but blow-up the dots that need plotting. In the example I draw 4 pixels for every point from the bitmap:
    ; Set coordinates for drawing the 'D'
    mov si, offset Hert
    mov yi, 30
    mov yf, 36 + 6
    mov xi, 30
    mov xf, 39 + 9
    call draw
    
    ; Exit program
    mov ah, 04ch
    int 21h
main endp

; Draw procedure to plot the 'D' on screen
draw proc
    mov ah, 0ch          ; Function to plot pixel
    mov dx, yi           ; Y coordinate start
y:
    mov cx, xi           ; X coordinate start
x:
    mov al, [si]         ; Get pixel color value

    int 10h              ; Draw pixel upper-left corner
    inc cx
    int 10h              ; Draw pixel upper-right corner
    inc dx
    int 10h              ; Draw pixel lower-left corner
    dec cx
    int 10h              ; Draw pixel lower-right corner
    dec dx

    inc si               ; Move to next pixel in data
    ADD cx, 2            ; Increment X coordinate
    cmp cx, xf           ; Check if end of X reached
    jb x
    ADD dx, 2            ; Move to next line in Y
    cmp dx, yf           ; Check if end of Y reached
    jb y
    ret

Your 9x6 character has now become an 18x12 character.
